# How can I reset the defaults settings in Unity?

Tags: 10.10, unity, command-line, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I have been experimenting with window managers and now I misconfigured compiz, to me it would be useful a terminal command

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the configuration files/folders of unity in your home folder,. seems like .unity or .local/share/unity

and probably the the unity gconf setting. Search in .gconf folder.