# How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?

Tags: gnome, configuration

I was playing around with some settings, and now I need to reset GNOME to it's defaults - how do I do that?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For Unity-related configuration resetting, [take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration).

For Ubuntu 17.10 and higher, [you can reset all the settings using dconf](https://askubuntu.com/a/959976/172367).

***This command will delete your configuration files. Once it's run there is no going back!***

Still with me?

### GNOME 2

Run the following on a terminal or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

That will remove all the GNOME 2 configuration settings. Log out, and log back in. You'll be back to a stock desktop.

You can backup before playing around with your settings in the future:

```
mkdir ./.old-gnome-config && mv ./.gnome* ./.old-gnome-config && mv .gconf* ./.old-gnome-config && mv ./.metacity ./.old-gnome-config
```

### GNOME 3

If your config isn't worth saving run the following:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
```

To back up and reset GNOME3:

```
mkdir ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.gnome* ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv .gconf* ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.metacity ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.cache ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.dbus ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.dmrc ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.mission-control ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.thumbnails ./.old-gnome-config/   && mv ~/.config/dconf/* ./.old-gnome-config/
```

Comment: more concise and precise to use a for loop for the backup step, e.g. `for f in .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity; do mv $f ${f}.bak; done` or `mkdir -p ~/.backup-gnome-config/ && for f in .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity; do mv $f ~/.backup-gnome-config/; done`

Comment: Shorten that last bit to `mkdir ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.gnome* .gconf* ./.metacity ./.cache ./.dbus ./.dmrc ./.mission-control ./.thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/* ./.old-gnome-config/`

Answer (score 29):

For 17.10+

There isn't a great solution but this may do the job or most of it.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Then log out/in

That command's path could be shortened if needing a more extensive reset, i.e. to just /org/ or even / but I'd go with above first.

Worst case one could also just go this in a terminal, I think it's a bit overkill as it will set all dconf (gsettings) back to defaults

```
mv .config/dconf/user .config/dconf/user.bak && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 21):

Fore me those directories were not sufficient - I had to delete `~/.config/dconf/user` as well.

This helped for me in those two cases:

- gnome-panel config broken
  (tried to specify location "left" for one gnome panel, it immediately crashed and could not be started afterwards)
- GTK Theme and GTK Icons broken
  (nevertheless the selection via e. g. `gnome-tweak-tool`, it remained in ugly Windows-style grey look and icons were standard gnome - I have no clue how this was provoked, it appeared suddenly after login)

This corresponds to the Gnome 3 Fallback Mode I use on Linux Mint 12 Lisa (Oneiric based). But the GTK problem persisted in all other login modes as well (MATE, Gnome 3 Standard)!

I am unsure now to which mechanism the `~/.config/dconf/user` file corresponds, as I found out that in Linux Mint only `_mateconf-editor_` is installed by default but outfitted with the title and icon of `gconf-editor` from Natty!
After installing `gconf-editor` additionally, this one is titled identically but has a different (new) icon. But don't rely on this icon stories, because this will rely on the icon theme which is Mint-X-Dark for me.

Theory says that `dconf` is the successor for `gconf`, but I found no information regarding the GUIs.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem and needed to remove ~/.config/dconf aswell

Comment: +1 for the info, but it'd be even better if you rewrite to incorporate your edits

Comment: This helped with the missing Lock Screen menu option (which is probably down to *yet* another corrupt dconf config)

Comment: Saved my life! Spent the last two hours unable to load my Ubuntu desktop, but deleting ~/.config/dconf/user did the trick

Comment: This is weird, i have to delete this file after every reboot to avoid login loop.

Comment: @OndraŽižka did you checked the permissions of this file?

Comment: This solved a problem for a co-worker of mine on CentOS. After a system update Gnome window manager was not running. We could see several files like .nfs00000000002a831f00000001 in the .config/dconf directory. (Users home directory mounted over nfs on network). I think these files are often a sign of network storage problems, maybe problems where parallel access to files happens. Anyway the .config/dconf/user file must have been corrupted. rm -rf .config/dconf/user solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to reset your GNOME specific settings to default as if you had never logged in try

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

Answer (score 4):

Logout, switch to command line (<kbd>Alt + Ctrl + F4</kbd>), login, do:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

Switch to X (<kbd>Alt + Ctrl + F2</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> on older versions).

Just like they described it [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/resetting-gnomes-settings-ubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

### Resetting Gnome Extensions

If you need to remove your Gnome Extensions (I ran into this problem when trying out Ubuntu 17.10 on an upgraded system) run:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Keep in mind that this will wipe all of your extensions.

To remove an individual extension, you can navigate to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and look for the extension's folder, then delete it.

### If you'd like to backup

To backup, run:

```
cp ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions-bkup
```

Comment: now my extensions don't load. any fix for that? I've installed the again from the site but either all don't work or just some works

Comment: @Tosho a couple of things: 1. Did you check to see that the extensions you installed are compatible with your Gnome Shell version? 2. Have you restarted Gnome Shell or logged out + logged back in?

Comment: I've re-installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 keeping my using my old /home partition. Now after some cleaning, re-installs and deleting, now most of them seems to work just fine. Only few extensions got ERROR after Updating from https://extensions.gnome.org or they crash randomly and restart doesn't fix anything. I'll leave it like it is for now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mv` command.

The syntax is:

```
mv source1 source2 source3 ... sourceN destination
```

In your case:

```
cd ~
mkdir .old-gnome-config
mv .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache \
.dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails .config/dconf/user \
.compiz* .old-gnome-config/
```

The last one is a directory and it's the destination.

Comment: Explanation: This is moving the old configuration to backup destination _./.old-gnome-config/_ it needs to be run in the home directory. Afterwards ubuntu restores the default configuration.

Comment: @mondjunge you have edted my comment. I'll do it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling `gnome-tweak-tool` resolved this issue and after reboot the GNOME 3 come up again. Actually `gnome-tweak-tool` was installed but the system detects it as a uninstalled one.

Comment: Are you saying that reinstalling `gnome-tweak-tool` actually resets GNOME settings to their defaults? Or just that it can fix some problems that might motivate someone to want to reset them?

Comment: Issue is Gnome settings reset. Reinstalling 'gnome-tweak-tool' does not reset Gnome settings.

Answer (score -1):

I did :

```
cd $HOME
cd .config
rm -R *
sudo reboot
```

And I've found my desktop like the first day I create my user account, but all my software params are the same (firefox, thunderbird, filezilla...)

Comment: Its help me.. Thanks @P-J Marquet

Comment: This resets EVERYTHING that uses ~/.config to store configuration data. NOT recommended.