# How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, configuration

I installed gnome from a kubuntu 11.04 installation using apt-get

`$ apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`

Everything was working just fine until I decided to change the panel format.
Then a tried to fix it following both those instructions, with no success:

[How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

[How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Nothing is working inside Gnome now, not even <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
I tried to uninstall and install it again, and I tried to install Unity too.

Any ideas in how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the problem affect all users or just one?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the first question you're linking to, removing Gnome directories from your home directory should definitely reset it to its default settings.

Can you double-check that the following folders **in your home folder** are indeed being deleted:

.gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity

The most bullet-proof way to do this is to log out, switch to a terminal with Alt-Ctrl-F1, log in **with your normal username** and invoke

```
cd $HOME
ls -la # see if the folders exist at this point
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
ls -la # confirm that the folders no longer exist
sudo reboot # just to be sure
```

If you can confirm that the directories are deleted and this doesn't fix the problem, then the problem is not related to your changes to the panel - most likely something you installed after you installed Gnome prevents it from working (Unity?)