# Can I reset Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-2d

I was playing around in Unity 2D, and I messed up my configuration. How can I reset it, preferably without losing other config files? (such as Empathy config, Firefox/Chrome config, etc)

Comment: @type: That *restarts* - I want to reset. For Unity, a simple `unity --reset` will do the trick - I want the equivalent for Unity 2D.

Comment: @jrg - can you clarify what you mean "messed up my configuration" - what is wrong?  Can you post a picture in your question?

Comment: @fossfreedom It's a hypothetical question - similar to [How do I reset my Unity configuration](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) and [How do I reset GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) - it's a legitimate question though.

Comment: Purge unity-2D and reinstall it

Comment: @tachyons That answer has been given on several occasions, but it doesn't remove *user* specific configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type

```
dconf reset -f /
```

to reset Unity 2D to defaults, or **IMPORTANT - THIS RESETS EVERYTHING NOT JUST UNITY-2D**

```
unity --reset
```

to reset Unity (3D).

If default Ubuntu Nautilus theme is also missing, close all instances and type

```
rm -R ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus
```

Comment: THIS RESETS EVERYTHING - do not use this on a casual basis!

Answer (score 0):

Although this link may seem off topic, it covers some of the information I believe you are looking for.

Edit: Whoops, I see fossfreedom was already on the case.

[Changing Unity Default Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

User: fossfreedom points out,

The list of sessions is described in the directory:

> /usr/share/xsessions

For unity-2d the session file is called:

> ubuntu-2d.desktop

fossfreedom goes on to explain how to reset this to default. Hopefully, this method would leave your files intact.

Regards,
SomaComa

Answer (score -4):

To reset unity type the following in the terminal:

```
unity --reset
```

To reset the unity icons type:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

To reset Compiz type (NOTE: this will reset ALL compiz settings):

```
   gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
unity --reset
```

The above command will reset the respective elements back to their default configuration.

Comment: Nope, that's for normal Unity. This is for Unity *2D*, not *3D*. Thanks for the answer though, it's already documented [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: Also, resetting compiz doesn't apply here, since Unity 2D uses metacity - Unity 3D is just a giant compiz plugin.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't thinking at the time I guess ;)