# How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, lightdm, auto-login

When autologon is active, `lightdm` will start the Unity 3D session, not the 2D (or any other shell that I want to auto-login to).

Is there a way to start the shell I want automatically (autologon)?

Anyway, if autologon is disabled, the last used session is launched, and that's fine. I just want to choose which is default with autologon.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The list of sessions is described in the directory `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Some of the more common session names are as follows:

- For unity-2d the session file is called *ubuntu-2d.desktop*
- For gnome-classic the session file is called *gnome-classic.desktop*
- For gnome-classic (no effects) aka gnome-fallback the session file is called *gnome-fallback.desktop*
- For unity-3d the session file is called *ubuntu.desktop*
- For Lubuntu the session file is called *Lubuntu.desktop*
- For LXDE the session file is called *LXDE.desktop*

Thus, if you change the light-dm configuration file to "ubuntu-2d" this will default the session to Unity-2D

i.e.

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

change the line

```
user-session=ubuntu
```

to

```
user-session=ubuntu-2d
```

Note - if you don't have a lightdm.conf file then for a autologin use the following values for this file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu-2d
autologin-user=myusername
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Another possibility is to run:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s <session-name>
```

E.g.:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d
```

This will also create the `lightdm.conf` file if it wasn't already present.

Comment: If the line `user-session=ubuntu` does not exist in the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, Then just type it in as the last line: `user-session=ubuntu-2d`

Comment: Worth noting that current distros (16.04 definitely) moves the config files into `/usr/share/lightdm/`. I had to edit `lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

Answer (score 24):

It is strange that [LightDM](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/) (Ubuntu 11.10's [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)), which [provides the graphical login screen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)) is not remembering your selection across reboots.

You can manually edit the relevant configuration file, which is called `.dmrc` and is located in your home folder. In Nautilus (the file browser), you'll have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (or *View* > *Show Hidden Files*) to see it and other files that start with a `.` character. If you have this file--which you probably do--then its contents will be like:

```
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu
```

For *GNOME Classic* you can change it to say:

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome-classic
```

Or for *GNOME Classic (no effects)* you can change it to say:

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome-fallback
```

If you happened to want to use Unity 2D (session type *Ubuntu 2D*), you could change it to say:

```
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu-2d
```

If you don't have the file at all, then you can create it with the appropriate contents.

If you want to set *GNOME Classic* or *GNOME Classic (no effects)* as the default session type for all users--or you'd prefer not to, but the above user-specific method doesn't work--then you can edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, changing the line that says `user-session=ubuntu` to instead say `user-session=gnome-classic` or `user-session=gnome-fallback` (or `user-session=ubuntu-2d`). A few things to keep in mind when considering doing this:

1. It is preferable to edit the per-user configuration files in users' home folders, unless you have a reason to prefer changing the global configuration (like that not working).
2. Since this is a global configuration file and it contains considerably more than the simple configuration option that you are intending to edit, it is advisable to back it up before editing it, in case you make a mistake. You can do that in the Terminal by running the command `sudo cp /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.old`.
3. This file is owned by root, hence the sudo command above. You must also edit it as root. To open it in gedit as root, you can run `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (either in a Terminal window, or in the graphical `Run Application` text box, when you can get by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) or `sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in a Terminal window.

It seems likely that the behavior you're experiencing is a bug, so after gathering additional information by seeing if manually editing `~/.dmrc` works, you may want to report it as one. [Read this carefully](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, then after searching to see if a similar bug has been reported, initiate the reporting process by invoking `ubuntu-bug` with the PID of the running `lightdm` process, or, almost as good, run `ubuntu-bug lightdm` ...which should all make sense after you've read [that guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

By the way, besides Unity (session type *Ubuntu*), Unity 2D (session type *Ubuntu 2D*), and GNOME 3 Fallback (*GNOME Classic* and *GNOME Classic (no effects)*), you might also consider, as even lighter-weight options, Xfce4 (install the package `xubuntu-desktop` and select session type *Xubuntu*) and LXDE (install the package `lubuntu-desktop` and select session type *Lubuntu*).

- **In newer versions of Ubuntu** than existed when this question was originally asked, [Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134346/why-is-unity-2d-being-discontinued) and GNOME 3 Fallback are not available. (In the newest versions, [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945142/why-are-unity-7-and-unity-8-discontinued-now) is not available either.) But [Xfce4](https://xfce.org/)/[Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) and [LXDE](https://lxde.org/)/[Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) remain available.
- These days, users who who have used GNOME 3 Fallback are likely to prefer the [MATE](https://mate-desktop.org/) desktop environment, provided by the `ubuntu-mate-desktop` package (see [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)).
- Lubuntu remains [more lightweight](https://askubuntu.com/a/413614/22949) (i.e., it tends to consume the fewest resources and to work acceptably on more old hardware). But it is not as fully featured as Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE.

There's also GNOME 3 with the GNOME Shell instead of Unity (install the package `gnome-shell` and select `GNOME`) and KDE 4 Plasma (install the package `kubuntu-desktop` and select `Kubuntu`), but those unlikely to be less resource-intensive than the above options.

Answer (score 17):

to change the default per user, check

> `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`

seems like this set's the `.dmrc` in the user home.

cheers

Answer (score 13):

To change the default Session in Lightdm

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session gnome-shell
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted gnome shell, but I found it with `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session gnome-shell`

Comment: no problem. I couldn't test it but the documentation I foudn suggested gnome for 'gnome-shell'. Did passing gnome for session give an error? Then I should edit my answer

Comment: no, but it went into the old gnome 2.

Answer (score 3):

I edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with this content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=gnome-shell
autologin-user=paul
```

And it starts automatically to gnome-shell.

Answer (score 1):

I find that setting any of the above is overridden by the users last session stored by lightdm. You may have to remove or edit the user files at `/var/cache/lightdm/dmrc` to enable the global default setting. Or on an individual basis by editing the `user.dmrc` file that has the following contents:

```
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu
```

Comment: What exactly is the `.dmrc` file and how is it created?

Answer (score 1):

This may not work in Ubuntu but it worked for me in Fedora.  It took days to figure out and I wanted to share it:

Go to `/usr/share/xsessions` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions` and add prefixes with a different number and a dash to every file ending in **.desktop**.
The lowest number will be the default.  For example, I want xfce to be my default so that file is named **1-xfce.desktop**

Hope this helps.