# How can I boot only with unity2d?

Tags: 11.10, boot, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for LightDM when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins)

I'm trying only use unity-2d on 11.10, have you got any idea about this simple possibility?
thanks!

Comment: You really need to add more information here, why cant you boot to unity2d? You can do that be selecting it on the session cogwheel in lightdm.

Comment: sorry my question was not explicit enough! 

Of couse I knowed to log out before to ask, but, despite this manipulation, when I reboot I find again unity-3d (may I precise I don't use log screen but automatic connexion )...

Answer (score 0):

1. If enabled, disable automatic login.
2. Log out.
3. Click on the cog icon next to your name in teh login screen.
4. Choose *Ubuntu 2D*.
5. Type your password and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the login screen, click the little cog icon, and click "Ubuntu 2D".  Not only will you now have Unity 2D, but it'll remember that you use Unity 2D instead of something else.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d` will make unity2d the default desktop if your are using auto-login as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins).