# Autologin to gnome-shell in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for LightDM when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins)

I've installed gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.10 from official repository. But after the choosing GNOME session at the greeter window, login in gnome-shell and after this rebooting, it doesn't boot automaticaly to gnome-shell(as was before with unity session). It just stops at the greeter window with option to type password and choose the session. 
How to make autologin to gnome-shell?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "System Settings" and then "User Account". In there you can change the setting to automatic login.

Comment: Yes, it's already set there for automatic login but doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, try http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins, and just change it to your values.