# How to default to Unity 2D on auto login

Tags: unity, unity-2d, auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for LightDM when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins)

When I auto-login it gives me unity 3D. How do I change the default to the 2D counterpart?