# "Normal" Ubuntu does not work after update to 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and now the "normal" Ubuntu does not work. I guess there are some issues with the video drivers (I have a Dell Inspiron 1545). All I can see is a bar at the top and the wallpaper - no gnome interface, no unity.

To fix this I have to logout and choose Ubuntu 2D. Any suggestion how I can fix this completely, e.g. by getting "normal" Ubuntu to work or set Ubuntu 2D as default?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu2D is the default desktop in 11.10 if you dont want to use Ubuntu3D. If you dont want to use Ubuntu3D you will need to set Ubuntu2D as your default from now on.

Comment: How do I set Ubuntu2D as default? (Currently 3D is default)

Comment: on the login window select ubuntu2d and login, ubuntu will remember your current selection. you are using automatic login?

Comment: I am using automatic login and ubuntu does not remember the default desktop.

Comment: then check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins) it was already answered. gl!

Comment: thick the check box if you issue is solved. regards