# How can I use gnome shell by default instead of unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

I don't like unity much.  I have no trouble to log out and log back in with gnome, but if I reboot my computer it goes back into unity by default.  How can I make gnome default instead?

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't mention gnome shell, so Anarci's answer here is more appropriate.