# How do I set the GNOME Classic login to be the default with autologin?

Tags: lightdm, gnome-classic, auto-login

I changed to gnome classic fallback, I auto-login but it defaults to unity 3d, how do I make auto-login default to gnome classic?

Comment: Related to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins) but we need an answer for the classic mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auto log-in gnome classic desktop :

- `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`
- `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-classic`

Answer (score 10):

Run the following in a gome-terminal:

- If you want GNOME Classic with effects:

  `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-classic`
- If you want GNOME Classic without effects:

  `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-fallback`

Comment: gnome-fallback is perfect and what I need for my remote instance since screen updates aren't sent 100% during animations / screen redraws.

But I don't think this setting is getting set correctly as Libre Office is still doing silly window resizing when multiple are open and I click its launcher icon.

How can I verify this command has been sent correctly and is sticking?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has no lightdm-set-defaults

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 14.04

I followed the post [here](http://www.jakenovak.com/gnome-fallback-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-autologin/)

Summary :

- Install the lightdm-webkit-greeter package: 
  ***sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter -y***.
- Open the ***/etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf*** file in your favorite text editor.
- Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=gnome-fallback
```