# How to make XFCE default for logging into Ubuntu other than Unity

Tags: unity, xfce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

I want to use XFCE every time I use Ubuntu, but instead I have to log out and log back in choosing XFCE each time I want to use it. How do I tell Ubuntu to choose XFCE instead of Unity by default?

Comment: if this is for 11.10 and you are using autologin - then this question and answer should help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins/62836#62836