# How do I automatically log into Gnome 3 Fallback Mode instead of Unity3D or Gnome Shell?

Tags: auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Is it possible to automatically login to Gnome3 "fallback" mode in Ubuntu 11.10 when starting up instead of Unity3D by default?  I've tried changing it at the login screen but it ignores my selection on the next reboot and defaults to Unity.

Running on an underpowered notebook, Fallback mode the only sane selection for the low specs of the system.

Any help will be appreciated.