# How do I make Gnome the default desktop?

Tags: gnome, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Every time I restart my computer it auto-logs me into the Unity desktop, is there some way to make Gnome the default choice, I hate having to log out every time and switch to it.

Comment: Your preferred desktop should be remembered automatically. If it doesn't, it's a bug. Report it on Launchpad.net. In the future, please try to provide information about what version of Ubuntu you're using. It makes things easier.

Comment: Disable auto login, then choose to log into the Gnome session upon reboot, Gnome will be the default as it was your previous session.

Answer (score 1):

To make Ubuntu 11.10 auto log-in gnome-shell, open up a terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
```

If you want to change back to Unity, run:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

`gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and you will see something similar to

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xubuntu
```

just change the session and save