# Making gnome-shell default

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Any way to make gnome-shell as default window manager other than adding
`gnome-shell --replace`' with in the startup application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By selecting gnome-shell at login from the drop down box pictured here: 
[image: select gnome here]

It should automatically be set to default for future logins until you select a different window manager.

If it doesn't automatically default the gnome-shell than you can edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and change

```
user-session=ubuntu
```

to

```
user-session=gnome
```

EDITED: to add how to change default manually.

Comment: No. I have to set GNOME everytime i login
I tried by removing unity Now i dont have a window manager no borders and menu :(

Comment: would you try sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell sudo apt-get install gnome-shell.  You shouldn't have to remove unity to get it to set default.

Comment: i have unity-greeter I tried to reinstalling gnome-shell and another solution dbconf-editor also tried still it gets replaced by unity

Comment: try editing the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and changing ubuntu to gnome in user-session=ubuntu, see if that works.  May require a restart.