# How do I change the default session for all users?

Tags: lightdm, autostart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

I'm trying to change the default session manager for all existing users and new users, from Unity to something else. I cant seem to find the file were this info is stored or a command to change it.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Please ask your autostart question as a new one, thanks!

Comment: ^^ The answers in that question should apply to you as well.