# Why are Unity 7 and Unity 8 discontinued now?

Tags: unity

Similar to this question [Why is Unity 2D being discontinued?](https://askubuntu.com/q/134346/48372) and an fellow up on this one [Is Unity going to end in 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/945134/48372)

What was the official reason by Canonical to axed the project when it was love by some many of their users and innovative?

Comment: The links in this question have many upvotes indicating interest in the community. Why weren't they closed as primarily opinion based like the proposed close votes for this question? This question can arguably be less opinion based than the links because it asks for an "official reason" aka seeks a cited source.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix good point. The first we probably missed it, the second is closed as dupe to an objective question.

Comment: What's an objective question?

Comment: @MathCubes *What's an objective question?*: I think the answers to that would be subjective :p

Comment: @MathCubes I am not sure if you are sarcastic due to me not being a native speaker... With "objective" question I was referring to questions that are not "primarily opinion based". Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Didn't you read [the announcement post penned by Mark Shuttleworth](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/) at all? Selected quotes:

> I took the view that, if convergence was the future and we could
>   deliver it as free software, that would be widely appreciated both in
>   the free software community and in the technology industry, where
>   there is substantial frustration with the existing, closed,
>   alternatives available to manufacturers. I was wrong on both counts.

---

> The cloud and IoT story for Ubuntu is excellent and continues to
>   improve. You all probably know that most public cloud workloads, and
>   most private Linux cloud infrastructures, depend on Ubuntu. You might
>   also know that most of the IoT work in auto, robotics, networking, and
>   machine learning is also on Ubuntu, with Canonical providing
>   commercial services on many of those initiatives. The number and size
>   of commercial engagements around Ubuntu on cloud and IoT has grown
>   materially and consistently.

---

> The choice, ultimately, is to invest in the areas which are
>   contributing to the growth of the company. Those are Ubuntu itself,
>   for desktops, servers and VMs, our cloud infrastructure products
>   (OpenStack and Kubernetes) our cloud operations capabilities (MAAS,
>   LXD, Juju, BootStack), and our IoT story in snaps and Ubuntu Core. All
>   of those have communities, **customers, revenue and growth, the
>   ingredients for a great and independent company**, with scale and
>   momentum.

Plain English: no money in Unity.

Comment: You are still active here and have more rep then I last recall.  Alot more.

Comment: @MathCubes he's still under 100k so he's still a newbie :-D

Comment: @Rinzwind I remember when he just had like 20-30.

Comment: Ah, the good ol' days.

Comment: Does your reputation wrap around beyond 2^32 or something?

Comment: @Jos nope, got suspended for a day. :D

Answer (score 8):

Unity will be supported until Ubuntu 16.04 EOL (End of Life) which is April 2021 I believe.

Additionally, with interest by users such as yourself, a "fork" of Unity will be made (perhaps more than one) supported by a third party.

I expect that some of the looks and features of Unity that people have come to know and love will be ported over to the Gnome Desktop Environment (DE) which Ubuntu 18.04 will be based on. Two things to remember are:

1. Don't worry as Unity EOL is a long way off.
2. Developers listen to users like yourself and what you request.

---

This [article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/04/ubuntu-creator-takes-ceo-role-again-after-layoffs-and-death-of-unity/) explicitly quotes reasons for Ubuntu dropping Unity down the road:

> "If we are going to take outside money and go public, how efficient do
>   we need to be?" Shuttleworth said. "In a very cold commercial sense,
>   we have to bring those numbers into line and that leads to headcount
>   changes. One of those pieces I could not bring into line was Unity. We
>   can't go through that market process and ask for outside investor
>   money when there's something that big that doesn't have a revenue
>   story. That's the pinch we got into."

Translation: ***Unity costs a lot of money but doesn't earn revenue. Gnome DE is Free. Investors will like the change***.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes I anticipate the question will be closed within 24 hours but I don't want people to worry unnecessarily. Indeed other questions and answers have addressed the future of Unity so it might be nominated as a duplicate.

Comment: @MathCubes reading about ubuntu-MATE 17.10, it looks like many loved features in Unity  (7) have been made available in the ubuntu mate desktop, so users have other places they can go (if gnome is not for them, but the ubuntu-desktop team have been working on making gnome less of a shock too)

Comment: Closed or not, this is not an answer to the question. Also, if you anticipate an answer will be closed it's usually better to leave it as is, otherwise the Roomba process might be interfered.

Comment: This link is for those like me who didn't know (until a fortnight ago) what @AndreaLazzarotto is referring to when saying  [Roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333477/time-for-roomba-to-ignore-comments). There may be better links but it's the only one referenced back to me in [one of my questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354248/are-50k-unanswered-no-up-vote-questions-between-2008-april-2014-too-many?noredirect=1#comment499530_354248) where I first heard the word.

Comment: I hope it goes without saying that *predicting* that a question will be closed is no reason to avoid answering the question. Believing a question *should* be closed is usually a good reason not to answer it (though facilitating automatic deletion of the question strikes me as one of the least important reasons to avoid answering questions one thinks ought to be closed). In contrast, believing a question will be *wrongly* closed, opposing the closure, and voting to reopen the question are entirely consistent with posting an answer.

Comment: Another technique @Zanna recently taught me is to simply down vote the question. It will be automatically deleted if it has no answers. This allows you to squirrel away your daily 20 Close Vote quota. Plus it saves the close vote queue from being clogged up when you are on a project to mass delete abandoned questions on EOL versions.

Comment: @Eliah, yes, true. I still think it should be closed BTW, but anyways it doesn't really matter. My previous comment was given because the answer did not answer the question. It has now been edited and I retracted my downvote.