# Programmaticaly change lightdm autologin session type

Tags: configuration, python, lightdm, auto-login

I have problem with lightdm setting autologin session type (using my config tool). Lightdm logs into previously selected session. I see that autologin-session is UNIMPLEMENTED in version 1.2.1. Maybe I can somehow cheat lightdm? but it seems program writes actual state when stopping and overwrites my changes to /home/user/.dmrc and /var/cache/lightdm/user.dmrc.

At the current I have two sessions: default and kiosk. in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf I have line:
user-session=desktop

but after I logged into kiosk session it starts all the time.
Changing .dmrc and /var/cache/lightdm/dmrc/user.dmrc doesn't work.

I think I will try nodm display manager because what I really want to achieve is run GUI session choosen by admin in gui config tool. Another lower-level tool is rungetty - but I  don't know this program (I found some tutorials).

**Resolved!**

Finnaly, after 2 days of trying nodm, lxdm, rungetty, etc. I've found (not so)simple solution for `lightdm`:

```
dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Accounts /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 org.freedesktop.Accounts.User.SetXSession string:kiosk
```

this sets default xsession to `kiosk` for user with id `1000`.

In future there probably will be option `autologin-session` in config file doing the same (marked as `UNIMPLEMENTED` now).

Comment: You mean when you login Lightdm selects the type of the session(e.g. classic/unity2D/unity3D) used previously automatically?

Comment: yes. Lightdm selects prevously used session type when autologin is enabled. And I don't know how this info is stored on disk (.dmrc and /var/cache... doesn't work for me) .

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins) helps.

Comment: auto-login still always logs into the last session used, I haven't found a real solution to this, http://askubuntu.com/questions/137431/lightdm-run-desktop-for-one-session-this-session-only

Answer (score 1):

In lightDM, try this.

Open (gksu gedit) the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
Change the values (in # Seat configuration)
from:

```
#default-user=bob
#default-user-timeout=5
#pam-service=lightdm
```

to:

```
default-user=username
default-user-timeout=0
pam-service=lightdm-autologin
```

And you can do this to:
Edit /etc/gdm/custom.conf file.

```
[daemon]
TimedLoginEnable=false
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=(your username)
AutomaticLogin=(your username)
TimedLoginDelay=0
DefaultSession=gnome
```

Finally reboot it, This will automatically login your username.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me too. Maybe I've missed something. It is strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightdm-set-defaults to change sessions with a script or from the command-line if you don't want to edit the file.  Use the -s option.

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults

Usage:
  lightdm-set-defaults [OPTION...] - set lightdm default values

Help Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help options

Application Options:
  -d, --debug                 Enable debugging
  -k, --keep-old              Only update if no default already set
  -r, --remove                Remove default value if it's the current one
  -s, --session               Set default session
  -g, --greeter               Set default greeter
  -a, --autologin             Set autologin user
  -i, --hide-users            Set greeter-hide-users to true or false
  -m, --show-manual-login     Set show-manual-login to true or false
  -l, --allow-guest           Set allow-guest to true or false
```