# How to configure permanent autologin?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, auto-login, kiosk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)
>   [How to permanently disable LightDM greeter and enable autologin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142307/how-to-permanently-disable-lightdm-greeter-and-enable-autologin)

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu 12.04 machine as a kiosk and I would like it, on boot, to automatically log in as my kiosk user "kiosk", and start the appropriate display manager, in this case blackbox.

I have configured `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142307/how-to-permanently-disable-lightdm-greeter-and-enable-autologin) and have an appropriate `/usr/share/xsessions/blackbox.desktop` to launch blackbox.

I managed to get initial autologin by using the `dbus-send` method in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146265/programmaticaly-change-lightdm-autologin-session-type), however if I right-click and select "Exit" from blackbox, then I am taken back to the login screen.

How can I configure lightdm/ubuntu to always autologin as "kiosk" instead of displaying the login screen?

Or, failing that, how can I configure blackbox to not display a menu when I right-click?

Comment: I don't know what Blackbox is but if you want to set a profile to auto login you can open the user accounts program and select your account you want to auto login then unlock the dialogue and select auto login.

Answer (score 0):

As far as disabling the Exit button, have a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/blackbox) and [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/think-inside-the-box-with-blackbox/1062246) they explain that the default menu is located in /usr/share/blackbox/menu, but can be overidden with a ~/.blackbox/menu file referenced from a .blackboxrc. The man page also states that adding `blackbox` to your .xinitrc or .xsession will get blackbox to kill the X session on exit.

If you're doing a kiosk you'll have to make sure the account is locked down. That way, if somebody switches to a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1-7) they can't do any damage.