# How can I make Unity 2D the default session at start-up?

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, session

I want Ubuntu to always use Unity2D by default. I am using the latest version (12.04 LTS).

Comment: Does it not remember the last session, and start that automatically?  Or are you saying you want to start 2d no matter which one you last used?  There is some discussion on how to change the default [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/62833/39753)

Answer (score 9):

when logging in there is a symbol in the top right of the box (usually a ubuntu logo unless using something else) click on the logo and then click `ubuntu 2D` , if you dont change this , you will always log into unity 2d

Answer (score 7):

To set the default for all users, you can use

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d
```

or you can edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` directly. See this [documented version](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/trunk/view/head:/data/lightdm.conf).

Per-user settings are stored in either `$HOME/.dmrc` or in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER` . According to [this post](http://tim.purewhite.id.au/2012/05/when-did-linux-start-moving-away-from-its-simplicity/), the latter file may overwrite your .dmrc.

Comment: Do you need to reboot for this to take effect?

Answer (score -2):

Just log-in unity-2d, under `System Settings -> User Account`, unlock and enable `Automatic Login`.

My ubuntu 12.04 enables auto-login while installation. It auto-login last session I logged in.

Comment: This question is about making Unity2D the default session. Also enabling auto-login is not part of the question.