# Is it worth installing Ubuntu instead of wubi?

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-xp

I'm using wubi at the moment and my pc is really slow, is it worth deleting XP and formatting it to Ubuntu? Or (trying) to reset XP to factory settings?

PS: I have over 40 GB HARD DRIVE and hate having xp on my computer...

Thanks,
DJ Porter

Comment: You should possibly post your system specs for Improved answers.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the different desktop environments (Unity, KDE, Xfce, LXDE) concerning the amount of resources used is very important, more important than that involved by an application or other. For example, with just 1 gb of RAM, Unity and KDE are not good options, almost beyond reach, while Xfce works decently, and lxde flies. If you have less than 1 GB of RAM, go with LXDE/Lubuntu. So, while you should try a dual boot, try first Xubuntu or Lubuntu in wubi.

Comment: It also depends on your cpu and other specs. I have a Celeron 2.4ghz with 1 gb ram, and KDE runs very fast, Unity not so much.

Answer (score 1):

What are the specs of your computer? If you're new to linux, the best way to begin, is having a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows XP.

As the time passes, and you become more productive with Ubuntu, you could then remove Windows.

If you run Ubuntu and Windows on dual-boot, one OS won't interfer with the other, the only downside is disc space.

So i would say, dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, there's no need to remove Windows, unless you have litlle disc space.

If you dual-boot and still Ubuntu is slow, i recommend using a lighter distribution of Ubuntu like [XUbuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) (Ubuntu with XFCE), or [LUbuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (Ubuntu with LXDE).

In the other hand, if you really like Unity, try running your current Ubuntu with Unity 2D or Gnome Fallback Session.

Comment: I'm a TINY pc with over 40gb hard drive I'm dual booting at the moment but both operating systems are real slow

Comment: 40GB is more than enough for both O.S. What CPU do you have and what memory?

Comment: Sorry if I'm silly, as I'm a pc expert but what's a CPU?

Comment: And plus I'm not actually going to use windows

Comment: So remove Windows and try one of the above solutions i presented above

Comment: I'll remove windows with Ubuntu, as I'm running over 40GB, if that does not work I will download the light versions

Answer (score 0):

You can run Ubuntu from a live CD or USB stick, without any need to install it to your hard drive first. Try it out and see!

Comment: he already is...

Comment: wubi is not quite the same as running Ubuntu from a live CD or USB.

Comment: Correct, it is not the same, however it is already installed on the hard-drive via wubi, and surely running on liveCD won't be faster than running on wubi...? At any rate this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu on a seperate partition will speed up your machine, so it's definitely worth trying, but it won't make your computer super-fast. ([The docs suggest that 500Mb of RAM is needed to run Ubuntu well](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/), do you have that?) If you're not using XP then delete it, or reinstall it on a separate partition.

Ensure you are running [Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145359/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-the-default-session-at-start-up), and if it is still being slow try installing instead [Xubuntu](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEoQFjAA&url=http://xubuntu.org/&ei=XMQsUJm9Fqq40QWQr4DQDA&usg=AFQjCNEN6ck0zieLEWUAOOvETuT5zukstw), [Lubuntu](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEcQFjAA&url=http://lubuntu.net/&ei=a8QsUNH4OMqu0QXRjYGwDA&usg=AFQjCNFtOnSwfkoz7qc88uERCQUf4q7vWw) (runs on LXDE) or [Bodhi](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CGcQFjAA&url=http://www.bodhilinux.com/&ei=g8QsUKy-Bqej0QXgpoC4DA&usg=AFQjCNEGgYjyW0UeBTke62WVuBobQ2sbIQ) linux (runs on E17) - fastest is last, but all will give a significant speed improvement.