# Alternative screen lock out to Xscreensaver?

Tags: login-screen, xscreensaver, idle

In most operating systems like Windows this was a nice feature, that when I walked away from the computer for the set amount of time - lets say 15 minutes - it would go into suspend.  When I would press the power button it would bring me to the main "greeter" log in screen instead of having me enter a password at the screen saver.  For some reason Ubuntu uses the Xscreensaver thing which doesn't look right and should kick me to the lightdm greeter log in screen.  Can I set Xorg to log me off when I'm idle for a given amount of time and bypass Xscreensaver?

Answer (score 2):

I found a forum at [crunchbanglinux.org](http://crunchbanglinux.org) on how to either modify/change Xscreensaver. http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/18793/how-do-i-replace-xscreensaver/ Also here is a link to extra screen savers for Xscreensaver if you decide to stay with it. Included is a way to have an auto-disable script for Xscreensaver. http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/1069/howto-configure-xscreensaver-instead-of-gnomescreensaver/ I used it a couple years ago on Ubuntu 10.10.

---

Alright, to login to a different session instead of the auto-lock screen, I found this link which shows how to configure the settings. [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins) Anyway, here is the code:

EXAMPLE: `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` change the line

`user-session=ubuntu` to `user-session=ubuntu-2d`

Note - if you don't have a lightdm.conf file then for a autologin use the following values for this file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter  
user-session=ubuntu-2d    
autologin-user=myusername  
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Another possibility is to run:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s <session-name>
```

EXAMPLE:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d
```

This will also create the `lightdm.conf` file if it wasn't already present.

---

Credit is due to **fossfreedom** for this tutorial.

Oh and one more link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM/. It's a wiki to LightDM configuration from canonical.

Let me know if this was what you were looking for. I tried to make it neat and easy to read.

Comment: Is there a way to make the computer log itself off?

Comment: Do you mean after a specific amount of time?

Comment: Yes, like when the computer goes into suspend after not using it for 15 minutes.  If there's a way to make it go to the log in screen at the main greeter when it wakes up on suspend instead of going straight to the desktop...

Comment: I'll test that on my other machine and see if it works...