# How to check if everything is ok with Unity3D in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, reboot

Please read the full post and then judge me.

As suggested, to setup Unity3D mode I at first checked  `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and Unity 3D support came positive.

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 630/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.14

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

So I tried `unity --reset` to set unity3D.

But after that, terminal just halted with a error message and repeatedly provided same error provided many-times. I opened a new terminal and reboot the system. And to my utter surprise, then I logged in, Unity3D was enabled! With system monitor I found Compiz running! And MyUnity star-up provided ***no***  message like one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171853/how-to-change-from-unity-2d-to-3d)

My CompizConfigSettingManager is running properly.

Can I guess everything is ok? Not to mention, I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually, you had to run `sudo restart lightdm`. And if everything is OK now, you have nothing to investigate.