# How to set GNOME Classic (no effects) as default?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I am wondering is there a possibility that every time I logged in to my Ubuntu, the desktop is set to Gnome Classic (no effect)? It is too redundant to set and choose it in the login every time.

Comment: This should be what happens by default.  The one I log in with is always the default next log in.  Are you sure this isn't the same for you?

Comment: So by then, I have an issue here. It always defaults to the Ubuntu the one with a launcher which I find annoying.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/62833/44179) question might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login screen always uses a user's last successfully logged-in session type as the default. If you don't change it, it logs in to the same interface you used before.

**If that is not happening**, that should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)). The affected package is `lightdm` (as LightDM provides the login screen in Ubuntu 12.04).

If the problem is that GNOME Classic is **not installed**, install the [gnome-session-fallback [image: Install gnome-session-fallback]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) package. In particular, if the problem is that you are selecting *Ubuntu 2D* as the session type and you get something that looks like Unity, that's normal--Unity and Unity 2D (provided by the *Ubuntu* and *Ubuntu 2D* session types, respectively) look very similar and both have launchers instead of a bottom panel containing a window list.

Whether or not this is due to a bug, it is also possible to set the default session type manually, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins). (However, if you're experiencing a bug, that also might or might not work. It would be valuable information for the bug report though, for you to indicate whether or not it does, so I recommend trying the techniques there.)

**If you are trying to run `gnome-panel` in Unity or Unity 2D** (as you [asked about here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247722/gnome-panel-where-is-it)), that will not be run automatically unless you configure your session to do so. `gnome-panel` is like any other program; to make it start automatically, use [an appropriate method here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically). Or follow the specific instructions for adding `gnome-panel` to your startup applications, that [Seth has added to his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/247728/22949).

Comment: That explains it.