# I've installed gnome-panel, where is it?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gnome-panel

I'm confused, I installed this **gnome-panel** from the Ubuntu Software Center. After that, I can't seem to locate where can I find it. All I see here in the preferences is this Compiz which I find not in favor of my minimalistic taste. I want to know the location where I can have preferences for the Gnome classic (no effect) desktop I set.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the GNOME Panel within Unity by running `gnome-panel` in a terminal.

If you want a look even more similar to the old GNOME 2:

- You can install [gnome-session-fallback [image: Install gnome-session-fallback]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) and choose *GNOME Classic* at the login screen.

  `gnome-session-fallback` can be installed in the Software Center or by running:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
  ```
- Or you can install the [Mate](http://mate-desktop.org/) desktop [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/q/87040/44179).

If you just want to have `gnome-panel` run when you log in, open "Startup Applications" either from the Unity Dash or the menu in Gnome Classic.  Click "Add" and put "gnome-panel" in the "Command" field.  You don't have to put anything in the "Name" or "Comment" field, they're optional.  Click "Add" again.

[image: Adding gnome-panel to Startup Applications.]