# "Unable to load session 'ubuntu'" in 12.04

Tags: unity, login, session

I removed Unity via the Software Store and rebooted.

Now I got the following error:

> unable to load session 'ubuntu'

I can't log in as guest either.

Comment: **When** did you get that error? Can you see the login screen? Can you enter in some TTY?

Answer (score 1):

Repair attempt:

Please open tty (virtual console, text mode only): `Ctrl+Alt+F1`

Enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

If above does not work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

### The install commands will tell self-explanatory if it’s already installed or not.

Credits: http://riveridea.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/how-to-solve-failed-to-load-session-ubuntu/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Because the problem is unable to load session 'ubuntu', So the solution might

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's returning Unity.

Comment: I think you wanna back to Ubuntu unity. To change to other session like gnome, maybe this link can help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins