# Ubuntu 11 display manager startup problem

Tags: xorg, gdm

Several days ago we had a power failure.
When I rebooted my Ubuntu Linux box, it initially came up displaying the F in the center of the screen but never went to the login.
Instead it goes to a black terminal look.
There is a cursor which responds to the mouse and an underline at the top left corner of the screen which does nothing.

The process list shows 4 `/usr/bin/Xorg` processes owned by root and  there are many processed owned by gdm.

gdm restart produces the following error:

```
[root@BTRC-Server01 ~]# gdm restart

** (gdm-binary:11700): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

** (gdm-binary:11700): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario like, your Ubuntu GDM(Display Manager) got corrupted due to sudden power failure & it can't be restarted so. Do one thing [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything) OR [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57704/is-there-a-ubuntu-sanity-check).

This links have good question answered correctly here on this site only.
Hope it'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it can be solved by:
[Type password into login screen, hit enter - nothing happens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390452/type-password-into-login-screen-hit-enter-nothing-happens/390475#390475)
(removing the files like in the second option helped me a couple of times)