# How to disable screen locking in Ubuntu 18.04/GNOME shell?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, lock-screen, gnome-shell

I'm missing a setting to disable screen locking in Ubuntu 18.04 with the default desktop GNOME shell. In versions < 18.04 (maybe < 17.10) it was possible to search "lock" in the Unity dashboard and it lead to the setting immediately (4 keystrokes and 2 clicks).

I want to disable the screen locking in a VirtualBox VM since protection against usage which is achieved by it is covered by the screen locking of the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable screen lock is available in Gnome settings, Pivacy.

You can also type this in a terminal :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

Comment: I have done this, but the screen still locks after a couple of minutes. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Does not work for me either. In fact, opening and closing Settings app twice causes the setting to revert back to true.

Comment: Didnt work for me either

Comment: Not sure it's related but I can't login after reboot after trying this solution. Just getting logged out instantly after typing the password it seems.

Answer (score 3):

go to settings > privacy >turn off screen lock
if you still end up in getting the screen saver or blank screen then > click on the 'power' which can be found in settings > power saving tab > opt for never

Comment: This answer is correct, although the way you suggest to access the settings is a bit uncommon, having to first access the Wired connection settings. Since you are suggesting the right top corner menu, you could very well suggest to click on the Settings icon on the bottom left of the menu and then click on Privacy. Or you could just search for Settings in the GNOME Shell overview, then Privacy, or you can even search for Privacy directly.