# ATI Graphics Driver in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, 14.04, radeon

I am using a Lenovo Ideapad laptop with graphics card configuration as **Radeon HD 8570A/8570M** on Ubuntu 14.04. It shows me "The System is running in low graphics mode" while booting. So i am following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) to solve my error.

I have tried `amd-catalyst 14.4` and `13.12` from [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Linux%20x86&rev=13.12) site. But while installing these drivers, my terminal goes like this:

[image]

When I click or close the message box, the installation stops.
So how do i install the appropriate driver?

Comment: Have you already tried to use fglrx from the Ubuntu repos? It should be as simple as running `sudo apt-get install fgrlx` or if you want a newer version `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`. Before running these commands, make sure to have the "restricted" repository enabled (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu ).

Comment: If you insist on installing the drivers from the AMD website, do not install them directly, but make distribution specific packages instead and install those. By this you will be able to uninstall the driver easily if you need to. The command should (I'm guessing) be: `./amd-gpu.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty`. Maybe `./amd-gpu.run --help` might be worth a look. Installation of .deb files might make troubles with Software Center, but should work with gdebi or using the command line.

Comment: @soulsource, i tries intalling fgrlx first. But after i install it, and  log in , nothing happens. The screen remains blank with no icons or topbar or sidebar like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears?lq=1


So i  uninstalled fglrx and did this http://askubuntu.com/questions/283985/unable-to-load-session-ubuntu-in-12-04/

Comment: It might sometimes be necessary to run `sudo aticonfig --initial` after installing fglrx. This will detect your screen setup and prepare an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. If you already have such a file, the current version will be backed up to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.original-0. Nevertheless, if you uninstall fglrx, make sure to put back the backup file of xorg.conf (or, if you didn't have an xorg.conf before running aticonfig, you should delete the xorg.conf file when uninstalling fglrx).

Comment: i installed fglrx again and also did sudo aticonfig --initial. But nothing comes after login screen.

Comment: That's quite strange. Could you upload the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log to pastebin and post the link?

Comment: Here is the log http://pastebin.com/XAYKqBVw  . I followed this tutorial but the same thing happens. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: Was fglrx installed when you collected the log file? I'm asking since the log says the fglrx X11 module could not be found.

Comment: no. it was no installed.Because if it would have been installed, i couldnt have logged in

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on my lenovo, it works.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216720

```
ganda@Lenovo-G400:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.0

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
```

Unity 3D supported:       yes

Comment: thanks @qanda for the help.My laptop was struck in the tty mode and it was crashing regularly.So i switched to windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running the installer as a normal user. Try to run it with: `sudo ./amd-gpu.run`

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: So, did worked?

Comment: Still the pop up boxes are coming as blank. THere are some other message boxes coming but with blank buttons and no text at all

Comment: BTW, i somehow install it and i get the message "Installation complete", but still the problem persist.