# how to set default session in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I have tried one of our site solution but its not working. the solution in our site is [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

But its not working for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

How to change session but not from login screen ?

Comment: You need to be more specific than simply saying, "It's not working."  Show the commands you ran and their output.  Show the contents of the config files you changed.  Explain exactly what you see on the screen and what should be happening.

Comment: @blujay why dont you try and then  give a comment with NEGATIVE vote. ok FYI: No lightdm.conf

Comment: I'm not going to upgrade my whole system to 14.04 right now just to try to solve your problem for you.  I downvoted your question because you didn't give enough information to solve the problem and didn't show what you had tried already.  So, now that you said that there's no `lightdm.conf` file: there's the problem!  Create the file, then try that solution again!

Comment: @blujay my system is not a trail & error one. Its development machine.

Comment: ...What?  Look, either run `touch lightdm.conf` and try the solution again, or don't.  I've given you the next step to perform.  If you refuse to do follow the directions you're given, why are you here?

Comment: @raaz yes, there is no `/etc/lightdm/lighdm.conf` but you may edit this `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for posting a good comment . Let me look for  user session in that file.

Comment: @AvinashRaj there i didnt see any line with user-session or similar thing to change session. any other ways ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have found it finally . look my answer.

Comment: See this link to:

[how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins/576361#576361

Comment: Have a look at this link too: [how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins/576361#576361

Comment: Have a look at this link too: [how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins/576361#576361

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok after some searching in config files , it did mentioned in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

open your terminal with ALT+CTRL+T and type as

`sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

and change line user-session to what session you want with session name as mentioned in /usr/share/xsessions/ with

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/
```