# How to install gnome having unity unchanged?

Tags: unity, gnome

I want to switch between unity and Gnome in the login screen. How should I do it.Is it possible to add any other interface like that in the lockscreen

Answer (score 1):

As answered previously by 
[Damian](https://askubuntu.com/users/63718/damian) Here [Installing Gnome Shell Desktop Enviroment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461677/installed-gnome-shell-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-14-04-but-its-not-working)

**You may also Download and Install Via Software Center** [Gnome Shell Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-shell/)

Just Install it like so

Open Terminal `CTRL + ALT + T` then copy and paste the following

**Use this commands (minimum installation):**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

**or simply this (normal installation):**

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then log out and on the login screen there should be a new icon after the password field click this and select Gnome.

**It has recently come to my attention that Gnome is unstable in Ubuntu and may cause issues with your system.**

Comment: you should mention that Gnome for Ubuntu is not stable, and definitely will cause many problems

Comment: Sorry next time I will do so. I thought since its in Ubuntu Software Center that it was stable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you install gnome from a regular Ubuntu install (i.e. unity)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

This should keep unity and have gnome available as an option, if I remeber correctly it's the icon which will have the current desktop environment icon, i.e. unity gnome, etc

I don't remember if it changes lightdm to gdm if you do it this way but if it does

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

that should reenable lightdm and have it as a default

I've been running GNOME exclusively for a while, but just switched the lightdm and gdm today due to a failed upgrade :/

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I now see Gnome(flash back) and Gnome(metacity) which I donot use in my login screen.I wish to remove it.Can you suggest any method