# 14.04: When changing the default desktop environment to to Gnome Flashback Compiz, and reboot I get a 'The system is running in low-graphics mode"

Tags: unity, gnome-classic, unity-greeter

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476793/how-to-change-the-default-desktop-environment-that-appears-in-the-greeter-in-1) tutorial, I managed to change the environment from "unity-greeter" to "gnome-fallback-compiz" and then I rebooted and I got this:

[image: lowgraphics.png]

Yeah, and all the options are pretty much useless to me which means delete and install. This is actually a clone of my Ubuntu VM so no progress has been lost :) but I never had an issue like this in 12.04, the previous LTS. Maybe I should try gnome-fallback instead of gnome-fallback-compiz but then its not compiz but really at this point I don't care. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: Is `gnome-fallback-compiz` not a safe mode Gnome?

Comment: @Zbunjeni I think it was back in 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was editing the wrong file. I was editing the greeter file rather than the file used in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Gnome3 shell, remove the `gnome-fallback-compiz`
Remove this in terminal, DON'T purge anything and install: 
`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: I'll try, but I do NOT want Gnome Shell if thats what your thinking, I am specifically making a version for a friend that uses the old fasion style gnome desktop environment to get them off 10.04

Comment: Try it anyway, then install `gnome-fallback-compiz`over it.

Comment: Its asking me weather to use lightdm or gdm? what do I choose? Lightdm?

Comment: take GDM, that is the gnome interface and gnome greeter

Comment: Anyways Idk what kind of awful gnome experience that was but it crashed when I restarted not with the same error, it couldn't recognise something and dropped me to the command line. I just deleted the VM, I think I'll try uninstalling Unity but keep unity as default for the launcher, that worked in 12.04 too I'll try tomorrow or when I have time.