# How do I set the default desktop environment on 18.04 (Bionic)?

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, gnome-flashback

I've installed Gnome Flashback and can select it on the log in screen:
[image]

Unfortunately, every time I restart I'm automatically logged into the original "Ubuntu" (Gnome 3) environment again. The solutions in these related questions don't work anymore:

[how to set default session in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456766/how-to-set-default-session-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

[How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Specifically, setting `user-session` to `gnome-flashback-metacity` in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` has no effect.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug because I have five DE's in 18.04 to pick from and whichever one I pick sticks as the default for the next login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround. Install LightDM (which IMHO looks much better than the default GDM):

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Then disable and re-enable autologin (if needed). This creates a working configuration that remembers your selected desktop environment.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

*(you can also add other DM via*

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 60
```

*[assuming the new session manager is /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic :-]*

Answer (score 6):

You can change the default Desktop environment file in user Account file.

```
cd /var/lib/AccountsService/users
```

Select the specific user file

Here change the "xsession" value to "GNOME Flahsback (Metacity)"

Comment: I needed unity, and was able to just specify `unity` (after installing it for 18.04), corresponding with the .desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions/

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Amazon Workspaces Ubuntu 22. I changed this file ./users/<username> and it included the line session=<nothing>. I put my DE of choice there, (e.g. i3) and on reboot it actually loaded it!

Answer (score 4):

You could reconfigure your default display manager using these steps in the terminal. I am assuming that your default is gdm3 and you want to move to lightdm

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
<OK>
lightdm
```

Comment: I’ve tried this but `dpkg-reconfigure` doesn’t offer any choices and immediately ends with exit code 0.

Comment: display manager and desktop are not the same, this answers a question, but a different one from the one that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

> Run sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm and select the default display manager
>   in the dialog that pops up. You can replace “gdm” with any of the
>   display managers that are currently installed on your system. If this
>   fails, you can edit the /etc/X11/default-display/manager file with
>   root privileges
>   https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/choose-switch-linux-display-managers/