# Change from i3 wm to Unity

Tags: unity, i3-wm

I have installed i3 and logged in by using i3 as GUI/Window Manager. Now, whenever I start Ubuntu, it automatically logs into i3. How can I go back using Unity as GUI? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049351/how-do-i-set-the-default-desktop-environment-on-18-04-bionic

Comment: @BrianZ No, unfortunately not. Whatever I do, I end up in i3.

Comment: In your login manager, first select the cog wheel on your login screen to select the Unity session. See the screenshot in the question someone linked as duplicate (although it is not) to see how this looks on gdm, the default login manager of Ubuntu 18.04 and up. The selection made there is remembered for future logins.

Comment: @vanadium That's exactly my problem, I don't see that cog wheel anymore, since I am logged in automatically. But knowing that gdm (and not lightdm) is the login manager might help in searching for a solution.

Comment: @pfnuesel So you've tried both `dpkg-reconfigure` and `update-alternative` as suggested in the answer I linked to?

Comment: @BrianZ Yes, I did.

Comment: Search how you can, at least temporarily, disable automatic login. Then you will be able to change the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and comment the two lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=Foo
```

Restart, and you should see the login screen again where you can choose the GUI/WM to be used.