# How do I set the default desktop environment on 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: gnome, 20.04

[How do I set the default desktop environment on 18.04 (Bionic)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049351/how-do-i-set-the-default-desktop-environment-on-18-04-bionic)

does not work in 20.04.1 LTS

/var/lib/AccountsService/users/root contains:

```
[com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService]
PlayerName=''
Timestamp=0
Title=''
Artist=''
Album=''
ArtUrl=''
PlayerIcon=<('themed', <['application-default-icon', 'application-default', 'application', 'application-default-icon-symbolic', 'application-default-symbolic', 'application-symbolic']>)>

[User]
Session=gnome-flashback-metacity
XSession=gnome-flashback-metacity
Icon=/root/.face
SystemAccount=true

[InputSource0]
xkb=us
```

However, whenever I login to the GUI splash screen as root, the "gear" shows the default as Ubuntu, not gnome flashback classic, forcing me to manually select this choice.  I want this choice *ONLY* for root, not for my regular user account (MATE that does not properly work for root).  How do I make the "gear" show all the choices, but with gnome classic as the default for root, and MATE as the default for myself?

Comment: Looks too difficult. What are the contents of `~/.dmrc` for both users?

Comment: There was no .dmrc .  I just added:-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43 Nov 19 11:20 .dmrc to ~/root with contents:  [Desktop]
Session=gnome-flashback-metacity  When I did a switch user to root, no effect -- the "gear" still showed Ubuntu as the default, although both MATE and gnome classic were shown as options.  Upon selecting gnome classic, the proper window manager environment activated.

Answer (score 1):

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/upgraded-to-20-04-and-the-menu-keeps-closing/21781/13

from:  saivinoba
Quality Assurance Tester

I found this issue (#871) on MATE's GitHub, discussing caja desktop behavior under root login. The solution is to have a local caja.desktop file for root user with --force-desktop option. It also states why desktop icons are disabled for root user. It is a good read.

As root (or sudo) do,
cp /usr/share/applications/caja.desktop /root/.local/share/applications/
and then append the Exec line as,
Exec=/usr/bin/caja --force-desktop .
Re-login and you will have desktop icons and application shortcuts.

After doing this, I (not the response above) noted:

I just did the above cp, edit of the .local version of caja.desktop , and then did a GUI switch user to root . Not only did this solve the desktop problem, it also solved the "brisk" MATE menu (standard current MATE upper panel user left end Menu drop-down) -- these no longer keep closing. As with other applications/environments, the Ubuntu implementation is designed to limit the functionality of root per se (not sudo that has other limitations); however, there are configuration file changes (as explained above for this case) to "restore" operational functionality. I just pinned Thunderbird to the root GUI desktop -- this allows me to switch user to root, invoke developer production Thunderbird without using the menu (not distro Thunderbird), and update (in place, not a full download of the tar.gz file) Thunderbird to production current. I then logout root and return to my enduser desktop (and account), with Thunderbird updated to developer production current.  End my response on the MATE fora.  Evidently, the --force-desktop switch (command line modifier) enables all of the expected functionality on a root GUI account use of MATE.