# How to change desktop environment from grub

Tags: boot, window-manager

I recently installed bpswm and I didnt install it  correctly so when I booted I got a black screen. And if I turn my laptop off and on again it boots automatically into bpswm because I had automatic login on. How can I fix this. Thank you

Comment: You don't use `grub` to select your desktop, you select the session (ie. desktop/WM) you'll use at the *greeter* or DM.  You've not provided any OS/release, but if you logout of your DE/WM session, you can select another one.  Your settings will dictate what is default; be it the last used, a specific DE/WM etc, and settings relate to *unstated* OS/release & packages installed.

Comment: The problem is I cant do anything except got to grub since it automatically logs in.

Comment: If you've told your system to auto login, that's what happens. Once logged in, you end the session (ie. logout) & return to your greeter & select another session.  Depending on details you've not provided (OS/release/product/packages..) that will be the new default; or just for the current session.  The system will do whatever you've told it to; currently that's autologin; and the DM selects the DE/WM/session, `grub` boots the system as it's a boot loader.

Comment: Is there nothing i can do? Because I cant log out since all it gives me is a black screen.

Comment: Grub or whatever boot loader you use, can pass some values thru to the booted system, but you've not provided any clues as to your software stack, thus we have no idea what options you have available; do you have a DM installed & setup to run - ie. you can select a new session; we only know what you tell us - currently we don't have know what OS/product/release you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default desktop environment on 18.04 (Bionic)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049351/how-do-i-set-the-default-desktop-environment-on-18-04-bionic)

Comment: I have other desktop environments to go to im currently using xubuntu but Im not sure which version I downloaded it around 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then set the desktop environment with the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Comment: I already tried that but when i press Ctrl+Alt+F3 it doesnt do anthing.

Comment: @AliMohammad Have you tried with F4, or F5, or F6?

Comment: Yes I just tried it it still doesnt do anthing