# Changing window manager in LightDM

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, window-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and wanted to change the default Unity/Compiz window manager. I've went through the [LightDM documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) and saw a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins), but I still can't make it work (I tried to switch both to xmonad and i3).

In my `/usr/share/xsessions/` I see the desktop files (for both i3 and xmonad), and I created a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-i3.conf` with the following content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=i3
```

Still, after rebooting I don't get i3 (same goes for xmonad). I'm not sure how to debug this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That specifies the default session, which doesn't change what a user who has logged in previously gets. Did you try manually selecting the session from the menu next to your username (usually a gear icon)?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thanks a lot!
If you will write this in a separate post I will be able to mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SeatDefaults` section, as expected, set the default values. However, once a user has already logged, the session they used (even if it was the default left unchanged) is taken as their session choice. So changes to `SeatDefaults` no longer apply to them. They'll have to manually select the session from the menu next to their username (usually a gear icon).