# restore compiz/unity as default window manager from xmonad

Tags: 14.04, unity, xmonad

I have installed and tried the xmonad window manager but now i want to switch back to compiz/unity as the default window manager. How can I do this?

I have tried

```
compiz --replace
```

but i get:

> compiz (core) - Error: Another window manager is already running on screen: 0

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the content of `~/.dmrc`?

It probably contains this:

```
[Desktop]
Session=xmonad
```

Mine currently shows this:

```
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu
```

So simply change the second line to `Session=ubuntu` instead of `Session=xmonad`.

Here's a relevant question:  [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Hopefully, that helps.