# Periodic lag while gaming

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I'm having problems with my Desktop when gaming. This is my first time using Linux, Elementary OS kind of didn't count since I was with it for only a month and barely used it due to driver issues and not being able to play games on it.

My Specs are of below:

- Intel Core 2 Quad
- Nvidia GeForce GT120 (Overcompensating on name cause it's weak haha)
- 4GB RAM
- Ubuntu 14.04.3

Now it's not the most elaborate or powerful setup there is, however back before Microsoft spied on us and gave me problems, it used to be able to run certain games perfectly fine, among them are Euro Truck Simulator 2, World of Warcraft, Fly for Fun (don't judge).

Since my move to Ubuntu however, it isn't as bad as Elementary OS, and I am able to play games, however I experience substantial lag spikes for a period of 2-3 minutes every 5-10 minutes of gameplay. Making the games no longer enjoyable. At first I thought it was just Euro Truck Simulator 2 acting up, later on I found it to be somewhat system wide. I've attempted to play the following games and experienced lag spikes

- Euro Truck Simulator 2
- Rochard
- Space Pirates and Zombies

Can anyone help me? I'm clueless here.

Comment: These games are on WINE or Steam (all have native linux versions on Steam) ? Do you have drivers for your GPU ?

Comment: @markkirby The 3 game that are listed are all Steam games, and yes they have their Linux versions through Steam. In terms of drivers, I installed them via "additional drivers". Is that the right way to do it? Or should I go find and download from Nvidia?

Comment: @markkirby, new development, running on Wine takes out a bit of lag on light games, ie. no lag. Still bummed no one has an suggestion on this issue though.

Comment: All I can think to suggest is open nvidia-settings from dash and under `open gl settings`, turn off `sync to vblank`, `allow flipping` and `use conformant texture clamping` as well as adjust the performance slider, then click `antialiasing settings` on the left and make sure all this is off or set to `application controlled`. Let me know ifany of this helps.

Comment: @markkirby I changed all the settings but still no luck. It still lags after some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System Requirements are different than they are for Windows.

**Euro Truck Simulator 2**

You don't meet the System Requirements for Linux.
[image]

You need at least an `Intel HD 4000`. You have a `Nvidia GeForce GT 120`.
As you can see from the benchmark `Intel HD 4000 GPU` performs better than NVIDIA.

[image]

**Rochard**

Rochard may run better in a Unity2D session.

[image]

[How do I change the default session unity-2d](https://askubuntu.com/a/62836/462639)

**Space Pirates and Zombies**

I think this might be in beta for Linux at the moment. 
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response to the question, I have previously noted, the computer performed fine despite not making minimum requirements on Windows. If you flip through the minimum for ETS2, both Windows and Linux have the same spec requirements. Seeing how this is system-wide with multiple ported Linux games, it's something else. However I'm slowly giving up on that idea, played around with every setting I know to no avail.