# Why doesn't `unity --reset` work?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, unity-2d, reset

I want to reset Unity. But when I type `unity --reset` I get the following error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXCreateContext failed
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
```

...
I am not using Compiz! I am using Metacity.

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT:

I am using Unity. And I want to reset it as the sidebar is always shown when I am viewing my desktop (although it hides automatically if I am using other applications) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches the windows in a different, poor way (not the default one of Ubuntu 11.10).

Answer (score 1):

Which Graphics card do you have?

Is ubuntu prompting you to install any restricted drivers? If yes, install them.

EDIT: If not check again by running jockey-gtk. Activate your graphics driver there.

According to `unity --help`, `unity --reset` is specific to compiz:

> --reset           Reset the unity profile in **compiz** and restart it.

So if you are just using unity 2d, then try resetting the profile by deleting the configuration file, but I only found how to reset all configurations for your user:

[Can I reset Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60715/can-i-reset-unity-2d)

But I think that you do not have to reset it all, just try:

```
dconf reset -f /desktop/unity/
```

I couldn't find any other unity entries in dconf. If it doesn't solve your problem, use dconf-editor to find any other entries in there.

Edit:

I have also found some unity-2d related settings in gconf under `/desktop/unity-2d`. I do not know how to reset these though, so post my value, which should be default as I am not using unity:

/desktop/unity-2d/launcher/favorites:

```
[ubiquity-gtkui.desktop,nautilus-home.desktop,firefox.desktop,libreoffice-writer.desktop,libreoffice-calc.desktop,libreoffice-impress.desktop,ubuntu-software-center.desktop,ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk.desktop]
```

/desktop/unity-2d/launcher/hide_mode: 2

/desktop/unity-2d/launcher/super_key_enable: yes

/desktop/unity-2d/launcher/user_strut: no

You haven't specified why you want to reset unity, but these gconf settings will only reset the favourite icons on the unity launcher and make unity hide when it is not active and trigger something on the super (windows) key.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

but I am using Unity (not Unity-2D). And I wan't to reset it because the sidebar is always shown  when i am viewing my desktop (Although it hides automatically if i am opening other applications)

Comment: @Elshaer Unity (not Unity-2d) without compiz is impossible afaik. So if you are not using compiz, then you are using unity-2d or something extremely dodgy. :)

Comment: @Elshaer setting /desktop/unity-2d/launcher/hide_mode to 2 in gconf-editor should solve your problem unless your not happy with the default setting either.

Comment: mmmm ... then I am using unity-2d :)
Thanks, I found that /desktop/unity-2d/launcher/hide_mode was already set to 2 !!

Comment: One more thing if i type "compiz --replace" it get "Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXCreateContext failed"

Comment: I don't care about metacity or compiz ... any one would be fine :D

Comment: Okay, well try to set it to other numbers (1, 3, 0?) maybe you will find the mode that you like...

Comment: glx is not working because either your graphics driver doesn't support it (unlikely) or because you haven't installed the driver. Find out which graphics card you use and install the driver for it.