# separate screen ati

Tags: xorg, ati, multiple-monitors

I'd like to have two separate screens (one for desktop, one for running XBMC on TV).
I have ati radeon 4850:
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV770 [Radeon HD 4850]
Now it works with X autoconfiguration (one big desktop - I have to move windowed xbmc to second screen and make it full screen with wmctrl). could you please help me with your working xorg.conf files which I could base my config on?

thanks in advance

c

Comment: ok, I managed to configure separate screens using proprieteraty ati driver, but the second screen (TV) doesn't get keyboard input and doesn't show window decorations. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing an issue with both Compiz and Nautilus.  They both don't handle separate X Screens very well.

Fortunately, you can disable Nautilus background and tell Metacity to decorate your windows on the second display:

- [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://askubuntu.com/a/68579/13247)
- `metacity --display :0.1 --replace`