# How can I reset my desktop to be like new?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gtk, reset

After I upgraded to 11.10, I made some mistake which totally destroyed Unity(I'm not sure at all what I did). I deleted all the configuration files that I knew of, and now at least it will start, but it's using the Raleigh theme and the Gnome icon theme. I can't do anything to change it in Gnome-Tweak or Appearance settings. The problem isn't just limited to unity; it affects Gnome, too. If login to the guest session, everything is fine.

The themes, theme engines, and icon themes **are** installed.

Note: I have tried everything, and no answer on this site has fixed my problem, including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

So is there a way to reset everything back the way it was, but still keep my bookmarks, passwords, and application settings?

`unity --reset` doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: The question you linked to is not exactly relevant to your case. BTW have you changed your theme in the appearance settings back to Ambiance?

Comment: @brunopereira81 it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Yes, I have changed it back and forth to all the themes. Also, the question I mentioned is very close to mine, but the solutions don't work for me.

Comment: See this. Doesn't seems to have a solution : http://askubuntu.com/questions/70572/reset-unity-and-gnome-to-default-values

Comment: The thing is, it is possible to reset your configuration, but you would lose a lot of settings for the applications you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying things out, I backed up my .config folder, created a new account, and replaced my config folder with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Since login to guest works nice why not create a new user, backup your files in to the new user account, delete the old user?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, everything in linux is a file. Therefore, this should be enough to reset gnome :

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

After removal, log out, and back log in.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any personal data stored in those directories?

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo As far as I know, no (**but I am not sure**). Bookmarks for firefox is in `~/.mozilla`. Similarly, other applications have their own directory in the home directory. Some KDE applications have their configurations in `~/.kde` directory, like for example kdevelop.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo I don't think so.