# How to clean/repair Ubuntu 12.04 when the stable comes out?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, beta

I've upgraded to Ubuntu Precise (12.04) Beta 1 and a lot of things are broken, I'm working my way around most issues and reporting the bugs.

I just wanted to know if there's a way do repair the whole system (like reinstalling every package) when the stable version comes out.. without reinstalling the OS.

All I want is to have the "fresh install" stability after the final 12.04 comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your packages constantly the OS should be almost stable by now and if you do it after the release all your packages will be the same version as a brand new one.

If you need you can reset your user configuration files to get rid of any old issue with them but there should not be any difference between the packages from a updated system and the packages from a fresh install.

For more information on how to do that please have a look at

- [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)
- [Reset Unity and Gnome to default values](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70572/reset-unity-and-gnome-to-default-values)

Comment: And the down vote comes because?