# Can't restore unity desktop

Tags: 12.04, unity

I'm having [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) problem.

Tried this:

```
$ unity --reset
```

This command hangs up on 'Setting Update "run_key"'

Also tried this:

```
$ ccmd
```

Unity plugin was disabled. I enabled it and rebooted. But still no luck.

Also tried this:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
$ rm -rf .compiz-1
$ sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Nothing happened.

Also tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,928 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 164812 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ubuntu-desktop 1.267 (using .../ubuntu-desktop_1.267_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ubuntu-desktop ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.267) ...
```

It didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: It didn't work =/

Comment: If that did not work, then take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/70572/reset-unity-and-gnome-to-default-values

Comment: Nothing works. Seems like a plugin is missing or something, and it breaks everything. I need something more drastic. Installing ubunt-desktop took a lot of time the first time (I installed from server edition) but I wouldn't care as long as I don't have to reinstall from live CD and lose my files. But this time with the '--reinstall' parameter it took just a second, not what I expected. Any ideas?