# Launcher bar in purple and only has icons for dash, trash, and workspaces; keyboard unresponsive, and menu bar empty

Tags: unity, launcher

Please help me reset or reinstall Unity. I've already tried everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146456/cant-restore-unity-desktop) as well as `apt-get update` and `upgrade`. My system entered this state after I re-installed the OS (12.04) in the hopes of curing its instability.

[image: Purple Launcher, empty title bar]

The curious thing is that Unity works if I go through recovery mode followed by resume.

Comment: Have you tried `unity --reset`?

Comment: And a LOT more. Please refer to link in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the simultaneous use of three video outputs (HDMI, VGA, and DVI) when only two can work at a time. I simply removed one of them and it booted right back up. Now that it is working I can re-attach all three and choose which two I want from the display settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install unity
```

Reboot your system.

If the above does't help, try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mono ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-desktop unity unity-common unity-2d
```

Comment: No change. Maybe some logs would help?