# Restore old desktop

Tags: updates, compiz, screen, update-manager

My Ubuntu Desktop display system has been crashed after automated updates via update manager. How can restore my old version of Ubuntu Desktop?
[image: Selecting any part and moving mouse anywhere cause this effect]

[image: A crash print screen]

Comment: I think new update was not proper to Compiz. As I logged out and logged again with Ubuntu 2D it is work fine but with normal login, same problems be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these three commands:

Instructions:

1. Log out of X.  I can't do this, since my logout menu didn't appears.
2. Find a virtual terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+F1) and login.
3. Kill X if you can't logout:

   ```
   sudo killall Xorg
   ```

   X will die, restart, and switch virtual terminal.  Switch back with Ctrl+Alt+F1.
4. Then run:

   ```
   mv -v ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1.BROKEN
   mv -v ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/dconf.BROKEN
   ```
5. Then go back to X (Ctrl+Alt+F7) and login.

   [Look Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/80988/139749)