# Problem with Nvidia driver 331.20 on ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

This is what I did:

- Pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Stopped `lightdm` and all that stuff
- Removed `nouveau` driver and installed `Nvidia 331.20` driver

Since then after loging in my computer I get a black screen and I can only get to the place where you log in and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/404845/installing-latest-nvidia-from-xorg-ppa-gives-black-screen

Answer (score 10):

The source of the problem probably starts with installing the `331` driver from the `.run` file provided by NVIDIA.

Here are the steps that worked for me and resolved both this and the [low-graphics mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399153/after-apt-get-upgrade-system-always-boot-to-low-graphics-mode) problem that subsequently came up.

[Remove Nvidia proprietary drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Add `xorg edgers` PPA for NVIDIA drivers and install `nvidia-331`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

[Remove/purge bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/a/400010/127101) and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee
sudo reboot
```

The following helped:

- [After apt-get upgrade system always boot to low-graphics mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399153/after-apt-get-upgrade-system-always-boot-to-low-graphics-mode)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197861

Comment: Removing the bumblebee did the trick! Many thanks. Resolved...(sigh)... another 2-hour torture session of dealing with video drivers on Linux. I'm guessing the reason this is so poorly managed is that canonical devs are preoccupied much more with building up Mir's pipeline then dealing with the Xorg pipeline. Driver install should resolve all these problems automatically (which would be easy to implement).

Comment: You last link explains it all: bumblebee is blacklisting all nvidia drivers... :-/

Comment: This fix just saved my day, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a similar situation. I removed all Nvidia drivers and associated programs and then manually re-installed the drivers from terminal mode. I believe, in my case, that an unknown Nvidia program conflicted with the Nvidia upgrade (3.19). With the screen black you will need to use terminal mode CTRL+ALT+FI to conduct all your work.

In my case, the initial re-boot "*failed*" after installing the updated driver (3.19), but I shut-down and rebooted and everything worked. What I have heard (unverified) is that the Nvidia graphic card is not immediately recognized by the computer when booting, hence initial failure.

I did a quick check and ran across this website: [Nvidia Driver 331.20 released, Install it in Ubuntu & Linux Mint](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/nvidia-331-20-install-ubuntu-linux-mint/). It may prove helpful.

This may prove helpful too: [Install NVIDIA GeForce driver in Ubuntu 13.10 / 13.04 / 12.10 / 12.04 using PPA](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

[How to change proprietary video driver using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line/335293#335293)

Also read the following: [Reset Unity and Gnome to default values [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70572/reset-unity-and-gnome-to-default-values) and [How To Reset Unity And Compiz In Ubuntu 13.10 Or 13.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html). I found them useful too.

Answer (score 0):

long shot but if you are using UEFI boot, just enable support for legacy boot in BIOS (do not fallback to it from UEFI) and see if you can get it to work (weird I know)