# Another black screen after Nvidia driver installing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, lightdm

I've installed the lastest Nvidia driver for my Graphic Card (a `.run` file), I've followed Nvidia instructions (http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/331.20/README/index.html) and placed `.run` file in home, then I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
cd ~
sudo source lightdm stop
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-133.20.run #(and I installed the driver)
sudo source lightdm start
```

After doing this every time I switch on the PC after the booting screen I can see just a black screen with a flashing underscore and I can't do anything, even open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F(n)</kbd>. I no longer see an Nvidia logo after the booting screen.

I tried to use recovery mode and (with "Drop to root shell prompt" mode) type `sudo source lightdm start`, but it gave me an error, then I tried `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but it couldn't find the file, then I tried to uninstall and reinstall anything related to Nvidia as shown here: [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver), but nothing.

What should I try in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `bumblebee` that is reported to be the source of problem with latest Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee
```

If this doesn't work, try purging all propietary Nvidia installed through the `.run` file, reinstall `nvidia-331` through PPA, then remove/purge `bumblebee`.

This worked for me in 13.10 (x64): [Problem with Nvidia driver 331.20 on ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379504/problem-with-nvidia-driver-331-20-on-ubuntu-13-10-64bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1. Boot into your BIOS/UEFI and Ensure you have "Discrete Graphics" selected instead of "Hybrid Graphics":

   [image]

   See more [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446682/327339).

   NVIDIA graphics drivers aren't compatible with "Hybrid Graphics", which uses your internal graphics card built into your CPU, as well.
2. Try installing a different NVIDIA driver. Start with the latest, then work your way down the list until you find one that works. Start with my answer here. It's for a different question, but the concept is the same. This answer links to yet another answer of mine with very detailed instructions to install the drivers: [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446675/327339)
3. Lastly, try to find your answer in the NVIDIA README: https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.60.11/README/ <-- update this URL for your exact driver version you are installing.