# Can't boot after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: boot

Ok, so I decided to install more recent drivers because I started experiencing some crashes with Rust. Don't think it's related, but that's the first thing I would do in windows.

So, I found out how to exit X and install it there, did it and it all looked fine. Went through the prompts, accepted everything and then restarted.

Now, every time I boot, I get past grub and then I get a black screen with a flashing dash.

I can get to recovery mode, but I don't know what to do there.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Which drivers did you install and how?

You can take a look at [How to change proprietary video driver using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line/335293#335293)
and [Problem with Nvidia driver 331.20 on ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379504/problem-with-nvidia-driver-331-20-on-ubuntu-13-10-64bit/413832#413832)

try:

`sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`

`sudo modprobe nvidia-331`

`sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`

Comment: It was the 331.38 driver, the latest one. I can't do any of those things since I can only access the recovery mode terminal and for some reason there isn't much I can do there.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu, tried your way and the same thing happened. Basically, installing new drivers makes my ubuntu installation unusable. Go figure. I guess I'll just give up and forever be on 319 drivers. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I had a similar issue with nvidia-331 drivers from xorg-edgers caused by the bumblebee package that black listed the nvidia-331 kernel module. sudo apt-get remove bumblebee resolved my problem. Check if you have that package installed and eventually remove it.