# Nvidia Go5600 video, black screen after login after 12.04 > 14.04 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

There are several questions and answers around this, and none seem to help.

I upgraded a laptop with an Nvidia NV31M GeForce FX Go5600 video adapter from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. I have tried the nvidia-173 driver, the nvidia-common driver and the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver with the same results.

When I boot the machine, it comes up and displays my walpaper on the screen the menu bar at the top and a login box and Ubuntu 14.04 at the bottom left exactly as I expect. At this point, ethernet is working and I can ssh into the machine and everything is normal from the ssh terminal.

If I try to log in on the console, either as myself or 'guest', I still see my wallpaper and Ubuntu 14.04 as I expect for some seconds. Then, at the point where it would normally display a desktop, the screen goes black. I have a  bright white cursor which I can move with the mouse or touchpad, but I see nothing else on the screen.

I can still communicate normally with the machine via ssh over the ethernet port, but I see nothing but the black screen and cursor on the laptop display.

There is an external VGA port on the machine, and I have connected a monitor to it with essentially the same results.

What more information can I provide to help figure this out?

Note 2015/06/05: Additional information. When I originally upgraded this machine from 11.10 to 12.04, I recall that there was an issue involving Nvidia and X11, and at the time I found a very helpful installation package that included an X11 downgrade of some kind that I think was required to make this work, although the symptom wasn't a black screen. I no longer recall what exactly I did, nor can I find anything either on the computer or online about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a desktop version of Ubuntu where I previously had the black screen problem. It was essentially resolved by aggressively removing all the nvidia files. My summary appears here: [Fixing/Repairing a Blank (Black) Screen in Ubuntu 13.04](http://srynas.blogspot.com/2013/08/fixingrepairing-blank-black-screen-in.html). Another potentially useful thread: [Problem with Nvidia driver 331.20 on Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379504/problem-with-nvidia-driver-331-20-on-ubuntu-13-10-64bit/379517#379517)  Whether the approaches outlined will work with a laptop are unknown to me.

You may also wish to review this Ask Ubuntu post: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)